# Runing own logic in container on top of nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm building SPA app that I would like to host in Docker container. App requires some configuration (e.g. url of backend). I decided to create short bash script that reads enviromental variables and assemble configuration file, but if I try to run it by CMD or ENTRYPOINT it dies immediately. I suppose that I override entrypoint in original docker file? Do I really need  to start nginx manually when I would be done with preparing this file?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have it easy: the [official nginx image](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/Dockerfile) doesn't declare an ENTRYPOINT, so you can add your own without conflicting with anything in the base image.  The important details here:

- When the entrypoint exits, the container is finished
- The entrypoint is passed the CMD or `docker run` command as arguments
- If the entrypoint is a shell script, it therefore usually wants to end with `exec "$@"`

A typical entrypoint script for this sort of thing might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i.bak -e "s/EXTERNAL_URL/$EXTERNAL_URL/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
exec "$@"
```

(For this specific task I've found [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html#index-envsubst) to be very useful, but I don't think it's present in the Alpine-based images; it's not a "standard" tool but it will be there in a full GNU-based runtime environment, like the Debian-based images have.  It goes through files and replaces `$VARIABLE` references with the contents of the matching environment variables.)

Comment: Just used `envsubst` successfully in a `nginx:mainline-alpine3.18-slim` Docker image :)

Comment: Since this was originally written, the `nginx` image _does_ contain an `ENTRYPOINT`, but more specifically one that runs `envsubst` on `/etc/nginx/template/*.template` files to write out `/etc/nginx/conf.d` files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are overriding the CMD.

**Recommended way:**

Try to use environment variable in your app when ever possible, This way you don't need to change the entrypoint/cmd of the official nginx container.

**If it's not possible:**

Nginx Dockerfile uses `"nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"` as cmd, you can override it by:

```
docker run -d --name yourapp-nginx <put other required docker switches here> <your image name:tag> /bin/sh -c '/path/to/yourscript.sh && /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"'
```

Or you can put it as CMD/Entrypoint in your Dockerfile, if you are building your own image.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I create my own container some of commands from parent containers are not executed. Despite of fact that nginx image exposes port 80, I had to add EXPOSE command to mine one

```
FROM nginx
ADD dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 80/tcp
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/ 
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Additionally I had to start nginx manually in my docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "{ backendUrl: '$BACKEND_URL'}" >> /usr/share/nginx/html/config

exec "$@"

nginx -g "daemon off;"
```